# Radio Button Check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to check if a radio box is checked using JavaScript, but I can't seem to figure it out properly.

This is the HTML code:

```
<input type="radio" name="status" id="employed_yes" value="yes">
<input type="radio" name="status" id="employed_no" value="no">
```

I have tried using jQuery as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#employed_yes').is(':checked')) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Also, I tried using pure Javascript by getting the element and check its 'checked' attribute, but it didn't work.

I look forward to your insight!

Thank you!

Comment: you are making the check on document ready, but as I can see in the HTMl code your input are not checked when the page loads. If you set the attribute checked on your HTML then your code will work, otherwise you have to make the check when the input is clicked or changed

Comment: The code works as expected, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/6pkBH/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use onchange

```
   $('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
        if($('#employed_yes').is(':checked')) {
          alert("yes");
        }
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h47Q6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check using name of the radio buttons like

```
if($('input[name="status"]').val() != "") {
    // do something
} else {
    alert("Select an Status");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution doesn't work because when the page loads the checkbox's default state is unchecked, which is when the jQuery code runs.

You need to listen for the change event on the checkbox like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#employed_yes").change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            document.write("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7CduY/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will alert `Hi` on document ready if the any radio button is checked. If you want to check on specific event then you can bind on any event to check same.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('input[type=radio]').is(':checked')) {
        alert("Hi");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`if($('input:radio:checked').text("yes") {
      // do something
}`

Got the idea from the jQuery forum. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-check-whether-all-radio-buttons-have-been-been-selected

Answer (score 0):

Dude, I think you Wanted, whether radio button is checked or not, this what i understand from your question

If so here it is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
        if($('[name=status]:checked').length) {
          alert("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h47Q6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS:

```
<input type = "button" value = "What?" name = "wic" onclick = "whatischecked(this.name);" />
```

Event onClick:

```
function whatischecked(name) {
        var 
            emp = document.getElementById("employed_yes").checked
            nonemp = document.getElementById("employed_no").checked

        if (emp) {
           alert("Employed");
        };

        if (nonemp) {
               alert("Non-Employed");
            };          

        if ((emp == false) & (nonemp == false))
        {
            alert("nothing checked")
        };  
    }
```